# What is the difference between Number() and ToNumber() in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. Can you please explain, why we have two functions that acting the same? what is the purpose of both?

```
ToNumber("100");
```

and

```
Number("100");
```

Comment: The difference is that `Number` is a javascript function, the other is not.

Comment: Where did you see `ToNumber`?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky
in the book of Suehring, Steve javascript step by step - ch5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only one is standard : `Number`

There's no standard `ToNumber` function. There's only [an abstract ToNumber operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) used as a description of a conversion process involved in many operations in the ECMAScript specification. If you have in your code a working call to `ToNumber`, this function was probably provided by a library you're using.

Comment: i should read ECMAScript specification documents.
Thank you :)